# Does this Haskell pattern have a name?

Tags: haskell

I recently found use for the following Haskell functions:

```
feed :: (a -> (a, b)) -> a -> Int -> (a, [b])
feed f input 0 = (input, [])
feed f input n
  | n < 0 = error "feed f input n: n < 0"
  | otherwise = (final, out:prev)
    where (next, out) = f input
      (final, prev) = feed f next $ pred n

nest :: (a -> a) -> a -> Int -> a
nest f x 0 = x
nest f x n
  | n < 0 = error "nest f x n: n < 0"
  | otherwise = f $ nest f x $ pred n
```

`feed` cycles a function through some input `a`, with the function returning a new input for the next call, as well as "emitting" an output, which is collected. `nest` works the same way, but doesn't let functions `emit` anything.

This looks awfully "Monadic" to me, and it seems to me like something from `Control.Monad` should already be doing this (I've caught myself trying to re-implement stuff like `sequence`, `mapM`, etc., out of necessity before, since I'm a beginner with Haskell and I don't quite know what's in the library and what's not.

Does something like the above (perhaps in a more general setting?) already exist? I've looked through the docs (at least the one's I'm familiar with), and can't find anything, though this seems like a common pattern. Example usage:

```
let pick10 rng = feed (swap . randomR (1, 10)) rng 10
```

Comment: Did I overlook something or shouldn't there be `feed f next $ pred (n - 1)` at the end of the `feed` function?

Comment: @Giorgio Isn't `pred (n - 1) = n - 2`? That would err on odd numbers.

Comment: I think the main thing you're poking at here is unfold. That's the most general concept of "seed function repeated on it's own outputs" which is twisted into various more *specific* things than unfold, but most of those can be built from unfold - for instance by attaching a bind operation to the seed function or other various things - but unfold is the most general concept of this (I believe?) or [Anamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism) in category theory

Comment: @VF1: Sorry I misread your code: I read `prev` (the variable) insted of `pred` (the function). I thought you needed to decrement the variable but you actually already do.

Comment: Regarding your question, I had thought about using a state or a writer monad to accumulate the list of results, but I have not been able to come up with a proper solution yet so I do not know if they would fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: This answer might be a bit more basic than you are looking for. Maybe someone will find it useful.

`feed` is a bit like [Data.List.unfoldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#g:9). It's not constrained to `Int`s. You could generalize yours over `Enum`s if you wanted. `iterate` is similar, but produces an infinite list.

```
Main Data.List> unfoldr (\x -> if x > 9 then Nothing else Just (x, x + 1)) 0
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
Main Data.List> feed (\x -> (x + 1, x)) 0 10
(10,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

`nest` is a bit like `iterate` because of infinite lists. Again, not constrained by the `Int` type.

```
*Main Data.List> iterate (+ 1.5) 2.7 !! 10
17.7
*Main Data.List> nest (+ 1.5) 2.7 10
17.7
```

As for Monadic, I'm not sure. `[a]` is one built-in Monad, and of course `unfoldr f` for whatever `f` is a nice `a -> [a]`. I do think you could define a Monad instance for your type (a, [b]) that left a trail and continued with the 'new' seed. There's probably an instance laying around that does that (Oop! You found it as I was writing this) - and, as always, these 'simple' things take just a few lines to write when you want them.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging it finally came to me. Indeed, there is such a generalization, and it was staring at me the whole time. The awfully monadic feeling I was getting was there because there really was a monad, simulated with tuples, lurking in the backgroud.

For those in suspense, it's `replicateM` along with `Control.Monad.Random` (for my example).

*Note*: I'll post a more detailed answer when I have time; just wanted to resolve the question to save viewers some effort.